# Why won't this div stay in place?

Tags: html, css

I am having a layout problem with my website.

Here is the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/N7apn/

```
<html></html>
```

I want the side-mod to be positioned to the right. This works fine when there are only three games in the list. But if there are any more, the side- gets placed underneath the games. I don't know why this is happening.

Could someone help me out with this problem please??

Thanks very much.

Comment: Please post a small example or make a jsfiddle

Comment: ok - I just made a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UL has no width set and is taking up the full width of the main container.

Set the width on your UL element of `width: 765px;`

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/N7apn/1/

P.S. Since you've floated both elements inside main container, you should clearfix the main container.